# Material progress dialog gradient

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-progressbar

I'm looking for a gradient support for the Material progress dialog. I just want to show a gradient along the arc that is drawn during the progress. Is there a chance to achieve this? Attached below an example of what I want to achieve. Currently, I'm using  [the SmoothProgressBar library from castorflex.](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar) Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend the `Drawable` used to draw the progressbar and then modify the `Paint` it uses by setting a `GradientShader` or a `BitmapShader` using the `setShader()` method. If this can't be done by extending it, your only way is to copy the class to your project and modify it there.

Update: the [CurcularProgressDrawable](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar/blob/master/library-circular/src/main/java/fr.castorflex.android.circularprogressbar/CircularProgressDrawable.java) class actually has a method that returns the Paint.

Comment: I'm using a SweepShader but I'm unable to draw a correct gradient. `float[] positions = {startAngle, sweepAngle};
    int[] colors = {mColors[0], mColors[1]};

    Shader gradient = new SweepGradient(10,300, colors, positions);
    paint.setShader(gradient);
    canvas.drawArc(mParent.getDrawableBounds(), startAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint);`

Comment: I bet it would be easier to make a gradient as a bitmap in Photoshop or something like that and then just use a BitmapShader (with an appropriate matrix if needed).